# Message selector in pub/sub and point to point

Tags: java, jms

While going through the book [`Java Message Service`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522045) i came across the below line which i am unable to comprehend:

> Another major difference between the pub/sub and p2p models is that,
>   with the pub/ sub model, message selectors are applied when the
>   message is copied to each subscriber; whereas with the p2p model,
>   message selectors are applied after the message has been added to the
>   queue.

I understand for pub/sub it says: before the broker sends the message to subscriber it applies the message selector but for point to point (queue) suppose 2 receivers have registered for the message than when it applies the message selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another major difference between the pub/sub and p2p models is that,
>   with the pub/ sub model, message selectors are applied when the
>   message is copied to each subscriber.

Since pub/sub sends a message to all subscribers, if the selector at the subscriber does not match the message, the message is likely dropped at the subcriber. The broker does not care which subscribers receive the message based on selector since pub/sub, by design, delivers to all subscribers. Based on that excerpt, that's my take.

> ...whereas with the p2p model, message selectors are applied after the
>   message has been added to the queue.

With queues, the broker must guarantee 'exactly-once' delivery for any given message, so selection occurs broker side first. Assume we have 3 consumers listening on the same queue, and they all have the same selector. In this case, the broker chooses one consumer, and delivers the message to that consumer only. If no consumers have a selector that matches the message, the broker retains the message until it finds a consumer, or until the message expires.